# Break While and Foreach Loop

Tags: php

I have the following code below, my question is, I want to break out of the while loop if the user enters "n" and also continue with the next foreach interation. Please see my comment within.

```
foreach($nodeid as $nid){

    $query= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM Nodes WHERE Node_ID = '$nid' AND New = 1")or die(mysql_error());

    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
    { 
        while (1) {
            fputs(STDOUT, "\n"."***New Node*** : $nid \n Do you want to add ? [y,n]: ");
            $response = strtolower(trim(fgets(STDIN)));
            if( $response == 'y' ) {
                #do something then break and go to next foreach.
            } elseif( $response == 'n' ) {
                #go to next foreach $nid
            } else {
                echo "\n", "I don't understand your option, let's try this again", "\n";
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so... add a `break;` ? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
continue 2;
```

in this case. This will continue with the next run of the outer foreach loop.

However, as @Tularis told in comments, a simple `break` would have the same effect here because no code is following the `while` loop. (and might be easier to read)

---

About the query. It looks like it would be better here to issue only one database query for all ids, using the `IN` statement:

```
$ids = impldode(',', $nodeids); // assuming the ids are integers
$query= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM Nodes WHERE Node_ID IN $ids AND New = 1")
```

Comment: or a simple `break` since there's no code after the end of the `while` loop it will continue with the next iteration of `foreach` automatically.

Comment: @Tularis yeah, you are right! :) have overseen this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use break notation:

```
    $foreach = array('a','b','c','d');
    $while = array('a','b','c','d');
    foreach($foreach as $key => $value){
        echo 'in foreach = '. $value.'<br/>';
        reset($while);
        while(current($while)){
            echo '&nbsp;&nbsp; in while = '. current($while).'<br/>';
            if(current($while) == 'b'){
                break;
            }
            next($while);
        }
    }
```

result :

```
in foreach = a
   in while = a
   in while = b
in foreach = b
   in while = a
   in while = b
in foreach = c
   in while = a
   in while = b
in foreach = d
   in while = a
   in while = b
```